# SQL MERGE statement with conditional MATCH clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

As you can see in the code below the `MERGE` statement is exactly the same except based on the IF statement I'm changing the column that will be merged into the target table. Is there a better way of writing this? As the number of `@Event`'s grow I don't want to be copying and pasting more and more of these as its not maintainable.

```
IF @Event = 1
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO SomeTable
    USING (
        -- Some Query
    ) AS A ON SomeTable.Id = A.Id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET SomeTable.Column1 = SomeTable.Column1 + 1;
END
ELSE IF @Event = 2
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO SomeTable
    USING (
        -- Some Query
    ) AS A ON SomeTable.Id = A.Id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET SomeTable.Column2 = SomeTable.Column2 + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a matter of debate whether one statement is better than two.  But, you can combine these:

```
MERGE INTO SomeTable
USING (
    -- Some Query
) AS A ON SomeTable.Id = A.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET SomeTable.Column1 = (CASE WHEN @Event = 1
                                         THEN SomeTable.Column1 + 1
                                         ELSE SomeTable.Column1
                                    END),
               SomeTable.Column2 = (CASE WHEN @Event = 2
                                         THEN SomeTable.Column2 + 1
                                         ELSE SomeTable.Column2
                                    END);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont really need a Merge statement for this and yes you can write your UPDATE statement a bit more dynamically. something like this.....

```
UPDATE ST
 SET ST.Column1 = CASE WHEN @Event = 1 
                     THEN ST.Column1 + 1 
                     ELSE ST.Column1 END
    ,ST.Column2 = CASE WHEN @Event = 2 
                     THEN ST.Column2 + 1 
                     ELSE ST.Column2 END
FROM SomeTable ST 
      INNER JOIN 
                (
                 -- Some Query
                ) AS A 
ON ST.Id = A.Id
```

Also you might want to read [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) as well though.